# Can't eliminate rows with na. Stata says ambiguous abbreviation

Tags: stata

In the dta file, there is this column

```
ColumnA
 1
 2
 1
 na
 .
 .
```

so I want to eliminate na and .

But when I do

```
drop if ColumnA==na
```

then Stata says (in red)

```
na ambiguous abbreviation
```

What is this? How can I successfully eliminate rows with "na" ?

Comment: Best to think and write not rows, but observations, not columns but variables, when working in Stata: that's for your own improved understanding when reading the documentation and gives extra clarity when reporting problems to more experienced users.

Answer (score 3):

This means that you have two (or more) variables that begin with the stub `na`. Stata interprets what you typed as `drop` the observation if the value of `ColumnA` is equal to value of variable `na`. Since Stata does not know which `na` variable you mean, it errors.

You should use either of these if `ColumnA` is a string variable:

```
drop if ColumnA == "na" | ColumnA == "." 
drop if inlist(ColumnA,"na",".")
```

If instead `ColumnA` is a numeric variable with integer values that has a value label attached, you need to specify the label name like this:

```
drop if ColumnA == "na":ColumnA_Value_Label
```

You can get the value label name with

```
describe ColumnA
```

Comment: In addition, `describe na*` will tell you which variables have names beginning `na`.