# Adding column based on ID in another data

Tags: stata

data1 is data from 1990 and it looks like

```
Panelkey   Region    income
 1           9           30
 2           1           20
 4           2           40
```

data2 is data from 2000 and it looks like

```
Panelkey   Region    income
  3          2           40
  2          1           30
  1          1           20
```

I want to add a column of where each person lived in 1990.

```
Panelkey    Region    income   Region1990
  3          2          40        .
  2          1          30        1
  1          1          20        9
```

How can I do this on Stata?

Comment: Take  a look at the -merge- command.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov  I am stuck with " do not uniquely identify observations \" error. But when it doesn't uniquely identify observations, I want to just choose any observation with that panelkey. That will work for me. How should I do this?

Comment: You don't tell us the `merge` code you tried. It will be some problem with your real dataset that you don't show us.

Comment: As in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112449/cant-eliminate-rows-with-na-stata-says-ambiguous-abbreviation the "column" terminology is alien here.

Comment: @user42459 You don't show what you typed and you don't show the complete error message. These would be necessary to diagnose what went wrong. It seems likely that you have a panel that lives in more than one region in 1990 or 2000.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will deal with panels that live in multiple regions in the same year by choosing the region with larger income. This would make sense if income was proportional to fraction of the year spent in a region. Same income ties will be broken arbitrarily using the highest region's value. Other types of aggregation might make sense (take a look at the -collapse- command).

Note that I tweaked your data by inserting second rows for the last observation in each year:

```
clear
input Panelkey   Region    income
 1           9           30
 2           1           20
 4           2           40
 4           10          80  
end
rename (Region income) =1990
bysort Panelkey (income Region): keep if _n==_N
isid Panelkey
save "data1990.dta", replace
clear
input Panelkey   Region    income
  3          2           40
  2          1           30
  1          1           20
  1          9           20
end
bysort Panelkey (income Region): keep if _n==_N
isid Panelkey
merge 1:1 Panelkey using "data1990.dta", keep(match master) nogen
list, clean noobs
```